# Is it okay to use tag name in CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a button that on click shows table containg actors. I called them:

```
<button class="actors">Show actors</button>
<table class="actors">...</div>
```

Then I need to access them in my CSS (and jQuery as well) so I use selectors like that:

```
button.actors {...}
table.actors {...}
```

Is it a good way to distinguish different elements with same classes? Or should I modify it so it looks like it:

```
<button class="actors-button">Show actors</button>
<table class="actors-table">...</div>
```

and

```
.actors-button {...}
.actors-table {...}
```

What I am really concerned about is selectors priority. Would't using tag names in selectors cause some hidden problem in future use (like IDs do)? Or is it just a matter of personal preference?

**P.S.**

Please don't post answers like 'just change button's class name to .show-actors and there will no problem'. It would be too easy and I don't want to do it ;)

Comment: Yes, it's a perfectly valid way of operating. However, adding more classes is usually preferred because making stuff explicit is *both more flexible and more readable*. As for *"selectors priority"*, some [recommended reading here](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Yeah you can add tag name too

Answer (score 0):

Using the element name in a selector is the *only* way to distinguish different elements with the same class, in general. (In special cases, you could use other contextual selectors, but that would be pointless and less flexible.)

If you are asking whether they should have different names, then that’s a matter of opinion and would heavily depend on the context and purpose of using classes, so it would be off-topic.

A selector like `button.actors` is more specific that a selector like `.actors-button` (rather trivially, since it is more complex). Selector specificity may cause “hidden problems”, but this is always a problem with selectors. In particular, in both approaches described in the question, the two selectors have the same specificity.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, I believe it is best to avoid using tag names, with some rare exceptions. One reason to avoid too generic selectors, like tag names, is that often it applies to "too many" elements. For example, if you have some third party components on your page (jquery plugins, polyfills, 3rd party ui components, etc.) - they too will be affected by the selectors. Sometimes this effect will be a negative one, because it will override the style defined by that component.

An exception to the rule is a CSS reset, for instance - where by definition you want to affect all elements on your page.
This is also the reason CSS frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation all define classes such as ".button" or ".btn", when they could have just used a "button" tag for the same purpose.

In addition, a class can be applied to different tags. So using a "button" class you can make an anchor ("a" tag) look like a button.